# Why does blender open randomly .blend files while rendering?

Tags: rendering, add-on

I have e really weird bug going on, first i couldn't believe it, but since it's repeating it's kinda creepy. When I let my pc rendering over night and checking for it the next morning, some other old blender files opened without my further do. The files are old and are not saved in the same file paths. Is this a bug, a virus or does somebody else had the same issues? My computer can't dedect a virus, can it be a corrupt addon or something? The other thing is, that I updated blender already a couple of times, so it can't be a bug, right? Pls help.